# Adding distance when buffering point geometry in a geodataframe?

Tags: coordinate-system, buffer, geopandas, python-3

I have 2 geodataframes that I want to combine. They the same fields/columns but different geometries (one is points, one is polygons).To do this I want to buffer the points slightly (like 10m or something) so that `points_gdf['geometry']` is changed to a "POLYGON". I tried changing to an projected crs that should be in meters first:

```
points_df = points_df.to_crs({'init': 'epsg:3174'})
points_df['geometry'] = points_df.geometry.buffer(10)
```

Once the `buffer` has completed, I concatenate it with my polygon geodataframe and change the `crs` back to the original.Then I write it to a shapefile to view it.

```
df_list = [poly_df, points_df]
final_combine = gpd.GeoDataFrame(pd.concat(df_list,sort=True))
final_combine.crs = {'init': 'epsg:4326'}
final_combine.to_file(final_out_feat)
```

When I view it, I am getting these giant polygon `points` that completely overshadow the other polygons. What could I be doing wrong here?

Comment: Almost always you are buffering in degrees instead of meters. Try projecting to EPSG 3857 as a test, although it seems that 3174 is indeed meters. Also, include the code you use to change the crs back to the original.